# Matching (Basic) Function Declarations

Tags: java, regex

I want to retrieve all function definitions individually from a source code file. Ultimately, I want to just retrieve all function names. Source files are of the following form:

```
#include bla

first_function_name()
{
}

second_function_name(first_parameter, second_parameter)
{
    i = 0;
}
```

Note that there are no access modifiers and return types, this is **NOT** for parsing the Java programming language.

I want to implement the solution via [regular expression](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html). So far I managed to match function definitions, however I'm having the problem that the regular expression doesn't only match a single function but also the ones coming afterwards. Basically, it doesn't end at the closing brace. I tried using the `$` symbol but it's also not ending the regular expression.

The regular expressions I'm currently using look like this:

```
private static final String FUNCTION_NAME_MATCHER = "[a-zA-Z]\\w*";
private static final String FUNCTION_MATCHER = "(?s)" + FUNCTION_NAME_MATCHER + "[(].*[)].*[\\{]([^\\}]*)?[\\}]";
```

How do I stop it from matching the following function(s) as well? It should match twice for the above example functions but instead it only matches once (both function definitions at once).

The method for getting a list of matched function definitions looks like this:

```
public List<String> getMatches()
{
    List<String> matchedResults = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(FUNCTION_MATCHER).matcher(sourceFile);

    while (matcher.find())
    {
        String functionDefinition = matcher.group();
        String functionName = functionDefinition.split(FUNCTION_NAME_MATCHER)[0];
        matchedResults.add(functionName);
    }

    return matchedResults;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a grammar for the language? Then you could use something like [Java Compiler Compiler](https://javacc.java.net/).

Comment: @AndyTurner:
Not really but it's a basic scripting language, nothing too extraordinary. It's based on C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
private static final String FUNCTION_NAME_MATCHER = "([a-zA-Z]\\w*)";
private static final String FUNCTION_MATCHER = "(?s)" + FUNCTION_NAME_MATCHER + "\\([^)]*\\)\\s*\\{[^}]*\\}";

public static List<String> getMatches()
{
    List<String> matchedResults = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(FUNCTION_MATCHER).matcher(sourceFile);

    while (matcher.find())
    {
        matchedResults.add(matcher.group(1));
    }

    return matchedResults;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`*`  is greedy, it will select every possible matching character that it can find. Right now the `[(].*[)]` part is consuming everything starting at the first `(` in the first function all the way to the last `)` in the *second*. You want to make it reluctant, where it will only consume a character if it needs to. Do so by changing all the `.*` to `.*?`

Also, you probably want to match only whitespace between the function declaration and body, so you should replace `[)].*[\\{]` with `[)]\\s*[\\{]`

If you enclose the `FUNCTION_NAME_MATCHER` and the arguments with `(` and `)` it will be captured into a capture group so you can extract it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'd want to match the whole function, to avoid matching function calls & duplicates:

```
[^\s]*\(([^}]*)\)\{([^}]*)}
```

Then, you want to split this up to get the name:

```
String matchedName = matchedFunction.split("(")[0]
```

And there you go! It's all done and dusted!